# Where is Dynamics CRM 2013 Xrm.Page Script Library Template?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK the Xrm.Page Script Library template was at **SDK\Templates\Xrm.PageScriptProjectTemplate** location. But in CRM 2013 SDK no such location exists.

Also no such file campe up in folder search.

Do anybody have an idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the template has not been released for CRM 2013.

You can use the CRM 2011 one, but of course will not contains the new client methods introduced with CRM 2013.

Comment: Is Microsoft planning to release the same?

Comment: you can add a request at Microsoft Connect, here a tutorial: http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/02/how-to-use-microsoft-connect-site.html

Answer (score 3):

I was the author of that template and chose to distribute it in the CRM SDK for CRM 2011. However, things got really busy and we just didn't have the bandwidth to maintain it. A third party solution: CRM Solution Manager (http://crmsolutionmanager.com) picked up the form scripting parts of it and added improvements along with many other useful capabilities. I would take a look at their solution if you found it helpful.

Comment: It's been almost 2 years Jim.  Any change in this that you know of?

Comment: No. While I still think this is a nice productivity enhancement, it isn't a blocking issue and there are alternatives.

Comment: I'm going to have to take a look at this one: https://fakexrmpage.codeplex.com/  It's in TypeScript which is even better!

Comment: @Daryl, did you have any luck with [FakeXrmPage](https://fakexrmpage.codeplex.com)?

Comment: @Dave Clark is doesn't use the definitely typed definitions for CRM, so I Abandoned it and instead created my own.  Hope to open source it at some point.